# How to create line break in ruby return statement

Tags: ruby

My code is this:

```
require 'date'

class Account
  attr_reader :date, :balance

  def initialize
    @balance = 0
    @date = DateTime.now.strftime "%d/%m/%Y"
    @transaction = ["date  ||  credit  ||  debit  ||  balance", "#{@date} ||  #{@credit}  ||  #{@debit}  ||  #{@balance}"]
  end

  def statement
    return @transaction.join("\n")
  end
end
```

I want to call `account = Account.new` and then `account.statement` to produce a line break between the two statements in the `@transaction` array.

The code prints `"\n"` as is instead of converting to a line break. It works if I use `puts` instead of `return`, but I need to use `return` in order for my RSpec tests to work.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking (and Ruby has implicit returns).

Comment: I'm asking is there a way to make account.statement to return the terms with a line break between them

Comment: @etieteeyen : add output value of `@transaction`

Comment: @transaction output value is "date  ||  credit  ||  debit  ||  balance\n30/10/2017 ||    ||    ||  0"

Comment: so how do i implement a line break between first and second statement?

Comment: The outputs seems to be correct, the `\n` is a line break.

Comment: Please show how you test your code.

Comment: I use irb by entering in the code and then like so:

    account = Account.new
    account.statement

Comment: So Gerry, if the output is correct, how come it prints \n and there isn't a line break shown?

Comment: you do not need to use return ruby always returns. If you want help with testing maybe try posting your test. Also you do realize that the second line of transaction will always just be a date and then a bunch of " || " because the other variables are nil when you are creating this string

Answer (score 2):

When you run code in the **console** (e.g. `irb` or `pry`), you see the *inspected* response of each line/method that gets executed.

For example, try the following:

```
> puts "hello\nworld"
hello
world

> "hello\nworld"
  => "hello\nworld"

> puts "hello\nworld".inspect
"hello\nworld"
```

This behaviour is an intentional, valuable feature of the console. It allows you to easy distinguish between different types of whitespace (tabs, spaces, newlines, carriage returns, ...); it allows you to distinguish between variable types (strings vs integers etc); it allows you to see non-printed characters, such as non-breaking space; and so on.

---

Your code above works fine. The `\n` **is** a new line character.

The only "issue" is that you are seeing it displayed in its escaped form (`\n`) *in the console*.

If you *print* the response in the console, you will see the newline displayed in its normal way:

```
> account = Account.new
> puts account.statement
```

Comment: By the way, unrelated but I'd highly recommend making `@transaction` into its own (array of??) objects, not just an array of strings like that. It looks like you're putting too much logic into the `Account` class.

Comment: Using strings to store data is a huge problem and a major anti-pattern, so it's worth stressing this. Converting to a string is a presentation problem and that should be done at the last possible moment. Preserve your data in its native format as long as possible.